# SSIS 2012 directory structure in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis

Recently i was given a task to upgrade SSIS packages from 2005 to 2012. They were not even on source control nor did they added packages to VS solution.

So i started with creating new VS solution and project. When i tried to organize packages into folder i couldn't find a way to create directories?

So my question is, is it possible to create directories for the SSIS packages?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not supported.  I would use projects or Solution Configurations.

Comment: Problem with projects is that then you cannot set subpackages to Project Reference type if they are in another project